# RxJava1 concatMap cause MissingBackpressureException

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to transform Observable using `concatMap`, since the order is important for my case.

```
@Test
fun load_data() {
    val sub = TestSubscriber<Long>()

    var s = BehaviorSubject.create<Long>()

    s.concatMap {
        Observable.timer(it, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
    .take(4)
    .subscribe(sub)

    s.onNext(5)
    s.onNext(6)
    s.onNext(7)
    s.onNext(8) //rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException

    sub.awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    sub.assertNoErrors()
}
```

*I have changed real data loading to `Observable.timer()` in order to simplify example and make it easier to reproduce.*

*I am using in the app `BehaviorSubject` to link UI actions with rx*

From [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap-rx.functions.Func1-), especially from marble diagram I expect that it will store items in queue and transform them one-by-one.

However it seems like `concatMap` has queue with size set only to 2 items. Adding more items cause `MissingBackpressureException`

So I have following questions:

1. Why `concatMap` has queue size 2 instead of `RxRingBuffer.SIZE` as
   other operators has?
2. Should I as a rule add any of `onBackpressure*` operators before 
   calling `concatMap` to prevent from `MissingBackpressureException` 
   exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer the questions, please consider switching to RxJava 2 where this is be not a problem with an `Observable`.

> Why concatMap has queue size 2 instead of RxRingBuffer.SIZE as other operators has?

The operator runs one `Observable` at a time and there was no reason to prefetch more than 1 in advance.

> Should I as a rule add any of onBackpressure* operators before calling concatMap to prevent from MissingBackpressureException exception?

Yes.

Comment: Yes, there should not be MissingBackpressureException with rxJava2, however migration will be time consuming due to big codebase.